# ¿Por que esta consulta no me devuelve resultados?

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta consulta a mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `Articulos` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`color`, '310') AND FIND_IN_SET(`talla`, '305') AND FIND_IN_SET(`empresa`, '199')
```

y aquí una captura de pantalla de php myadmin del listado de articulos donde se ve que si existe esa combinación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿que tengo mal para que me devuelva 0 si si hay resultados?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `Articulos` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('310', color) > 0 AND FIND_IN_SET('305', talla) > 0 ;

Comment: Ahora si... el caso es que poniéndolo al revés en empresa y color si funcionaba... mil gracias por tu ayuda @PatrickArguello

Comment: agregó como respuesta. Slds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sintaxis es FIND_IN_SET (search string, string list)

```
SELECT * FROM Articulos 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('310', color) > 0 AND 
          FIND_IN_SET('305', talla) > 0 ;
```